# Which elements of a group have equal centralizer?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can we say elements which has equal centralizers are the elements which are in the same coset of $G/Z(G)$? I mean if $C_G(x)=C_G(y)$, then $x=yz$ where $z\in Z(G)$ or $x=y^{-1}$. Are there any other elements of the group which have equal centralizer?

Answer (score 2):

If the centralizer of $x$ is normal, then the other elements in the same conjugacy class as $x$ will have the same centralizer. You can prove this by hand, but its easiest to see with group actions.

Answer (score 1):

What is the centralizer of $(1,2,3)$ in $S_5$? Can you think of other elements with the same centralizer? What is the center of $S_5$?

Comment: What do you really mean, I did not get your point, Can you explain it ?

Comment: I meant for you to actually compute the centralizer of that element, and possibly of others to see concretely in an easy example whether the claim you want is true or not.

Answer (score 1):

The centralizer of a subset only depends on the subgroup generated by that subset. Thus if $n$ is coprime to $|x|$, then $C_G(x) = C_G(x^n)$.

More generally, $C(x) = C(y)$ iff $C(C(x)) = C(C(y))$ iff $x$ and $y$ are in the same coset of $C(C(x)) \cap C(C(y))$, i.e. $x^{-1}y \in C(C(x)) \cap C(C(y))$. It is an interesting (although not very group-theoretic) question to ask when $C(H) = C(K)$ for two subgroups $H$ and $K$.

Answer (score 1):

if $C_G(x)=C_G(y)$ then for any element $a\in H$,

$C_G(x)\leq C_G(a)$ where $H=<x,y>$ is the subgroup generated $x$ and $y$

and as a result $C_G(x)=C_G(H)$ as $ C_G(H)=\bigcap C_G(a)$.

**proof:** Let $a\in H$ then $a=x^{r_1}y^{k_1}...x^{r_n}y^{k_n}$ and $m\in C_G(x)$.

Then clearly $mx^{r_i}m^{-1}=x^{r_i}$ and $my^{k_i}m^{-1}=y^{r_i}$,

$$mam^{-1}=mx^{r_1}y^{k_1}...x^{r_n}y^{k_n}m^{-1}$$
$$mam^{-1}=mx^{r_1}m^{-1}my^{k_1}m^{-1}...m^{-1}mx^{r_n}y^{k_n}m^{-1}$$
$$ =x^{r_1}y^{k_1}...x^{r_n}y^{k_n}=a$$

So $m\in C_G(a)$ so $C_G(H)=C_G(x)$.